# pvcreate command and setting of extents

Tags: lvm

I am trying to find the way to create a physical volume with specific range of extents. Vgcreate command has -s option for this(but this command is for groups). I read the man for pvcreate and did not find anything about setting extent size. Is there any way to create physical volume with specific number of extents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to do is specify the size of physical extent on the physical volume of a volume group.

This is defined in the volume group creation (with *vgcreate* as you indicate), not makes sense to do previously with *pvcreate* as this will only initialize a disk or partition for use with volumes of group and nothing more, the options offered by this command are regarding a physical initialization.

The definition of logical specifications, is managed in the volume group is where the physical extent size is defined.

I think the beginning to understand this is to associate pvcreate (**p**hysical **v**olume  **create**) to physical management, ie the disk or partition that physical part and vgcreate (**v**olume **g**roup **create**) with logic management initialized with pvcreate device and this is where define logical specifications as the physical extent size.

For reference you can consult the man pages of [pvcreate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvcreate) and [lvcreate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgcreate), although I think you have done this already but with another point of view.

At least, so as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify number of extents creating a PV... PV is just a device that 'looks' like a hard disk. You can do it creating LVs:

```
-l, --extents LogicalExtentsNumber[%{VG|PVS|FREE|ORIGIN}]
              Gives the number of logical extents to allocate for the new logical volume.  The  number  can
              also be expressed as a percentage of the total space in the Volume Group with the suffix %VG,
              as a percentage of the remaining free space in the Volume Group with the suffix %FREE,  as  a
              percentage  of  the  remaining free space for the specified PhysicalVolume(s) with the suffix
              %PVS, or (for a snapshot) as a percentage of the total space in  the  Origin  Logical  Volume
              with the suffix %ORIGIN.
```

Regards.